# trying to use POST, but API tries to use GET

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to get an api method to use POST but it insists on trying to use GET.  I've Googled and searched SO, but everything I try just returns the same message.

Here's my controller:

```
    [Route("api/game/{gameId}/createcharacter/{name}")]

    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostNewCharacter([FromBody]string name)
    {
        return Created("created", CharacterGenerationService.CreateNewCharacter(name));
    }
```

Here's the message I get no matter what I try:

> message: "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
>
> Request
>   URL:http://localhost:61645/api/game/452/createcharacter/testChar1
>   Request Method:GET Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed Remote
>   Address:[::1]:61645

I am using : using System.Web.Http;

Is there a trick to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

```
[Route("api/game/{gameId}/createcharacter/{name}")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostNewCharacter(string name)
{
    return Created("created", CharacterGenerationService.CreateNewCharacter(name));
}
```

Comment: Hi modified my code to look exactly like that, but still get the same message

Comment: how are you calling this? And have you enabled attribute routing?

Comment: Right now I'm just navigating to the route in my browser for testing.  How do I enable attribute routing?  Thanks!

Comment: If you are calling from browser addressbar , its GET request. that is why you are getting error. to enable attribut routing, add config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); in WebApiConfig.cs

Answer (score 0):

In the route template you said you will get the `name` parameter value from the URL but in the signature of your method your decorate that same parameter with `FromBody` attribute which tell that the value will be retrieved from the message body.

You have two choices :

- remove the `FromBody` attribute and your URL will work correctly
- or remove the **{name}** parameter in your route template and post the `name` value into your request body.

What about the `gameId` parameter ? 
Don't you need it in your method ?  If yes, then you need to pass it as a method parameter.

Comment: I did remove the FromBody so it looks like this: public IHttpActionResult PostNewCharacter(string name).  I rebuilt the solution, and I still get the exact same message.  :(

Comment: You need to add gameid parameter in your method.

Comment: I added in the gameId parameter, but I still get the same message

Comment: How did you compose your request ?